# Contour assignment in OpenCv - Tracking across frames of movie

Tags: opencv, identity, tracking, contour

I am interested in tracking objects across frames of a movie to calculate the velocity of each object. These are Drosophila in well plates. Therefore there are always 12 objects in every frame and the objects should not be allowed to merge. I have written a script that identifies each object and finds their centroids. It them minimizes the distances between those centroids and the ones detected on the previous frame.

What I am really surprised to see is that without even taking the previous centroids into consideration, openCV seems to do a really good job of automatically assigning each contour the same relative identity across frames. So if I plot my video with the contour number over each blob, that number hardly changes across frames? How does this work? How does OpenCV decide which contour will be returned first and which will be returned last?

Thank you,
FB